# Getting null value while consuming wcf service in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Getting null value while consuming wcf service in asp.net using c#. I am using this code.
kindly send me correct solution for doing this activity.

```
protected void rtrFile()
    {
       string newvar="";
        string url = "http://vinipost.com/Services/Mobile_Application/wcfService.svc/getGroup?usrId=100";
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
             newvar= streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        vpData fbdata = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<vpData>(newvar);

        GridView1.DataSource = fbdata.Data;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
  public class vpData
    {       
        public string getFriendsResult { get; set; }
        public List<vpkUser> Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class vpkUser
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: aha, this code :) p.s. where?

Comment: try using this,
newvar = Convert.ToString(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
also debug your code.

Comment: after using it, fbdata.Data is still showing null

Comment: did you debug the variable "newvar" ??

Comment: yes, in this variable data is showing but after Deserialize "newvar" and binding "fbdata.Data" with gridview then "fbdata.Data" is null

Comment: kindly reply, it is very urgent.

Comment: @user1846765: i think your Json and Model does not match check the answer below.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a block error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `model` and `JSON` does not Match:

Try this:

```
protected void rtrFile()
    {
        string newvar = "";
        string url = "http://vinipost.com/Services/Mobile_Application/wcfService.svc/getGroup?usrId=100";
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        newvar = streamReader.ReadToEnd();


        vpData fbdata = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<vpData>(newvar);

        GridView1.DataSource = fbdata.getGroupResult;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    public class vpData
    {     
        public List<vpkUser> getGroupResult { get; set; }
    }

    public class vpkUser
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
    protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rtrFile();
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much, solve my problem.